# How can I make an image slide from one side of the screen to a fixed position on the other?

Tags: html, css

I have two floating images on my page right now with a code looking like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#img1{
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#img2{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="IMAGE1.png" id="img1">
  <img src="IMAGE2.png" id="img2">
</body>
</html>
```

However, I'd like img2 to slide into it's position from the left and then stay there while img1 appears right after img2 finish its movement. And it needs to happen automatically as the webpage opens.

I've tried what I know but I'm still very much a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. It would be ideal if the images could then stay there while someone clicks through each page (it's a tumblr blog) and not reset every time.

Comment: JavaScript or CSS3 transforms?

Comment: you are going to need JavaScript for this. You can probably cache the current displayed image in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways as far as I know: Javascript and CSS3.

With JS, I would recommend using a library, like jQuery which already has an `animate` method which would come in handy: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**(Small edit)** If you want the animation to happen after the page loads, checkout the `.ready` method: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

With CSS3, you coud go with transition, read a bit more here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I've read through both of them - thank you - but it doesn't seem to have anything that makes it happen automatically when he page opens

Comment: For that, use `$(document).ready`, checkout the link I aded to the response.